# NodeJS execution error TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to execute my code below, But it's give me error for some reason. I've tried my best to debug, with failed attempt!

Can any one help me to find out what am doing wrong in code below?

```
var lastPos = 0;

function exec_code(){
    var fs = require('fs');
var child_process = require('child_process');
//var lastPos = 0;

function getFriends() {
    var friendsList = [];
    var friends = fs.readFileSync('usernames.txt');
    for (friend of friends.toString().split('\n')) {
        friend = friend.replace('\r', '');
        friendsList.push(friend);
    }
    return friendsList;
}

function getUsers() {
    var list = getFriends();
    var result  = list.splice(lastPos, 94)
    lastPos+=94;
    return result;
}

function getProxList(cb) {
    var temp = [];
    fs.readFile('proxies.txt', (err, lines) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (p of lines.toString().split('\n')) {
            temp.push({host: p.split(':')[0].replace('\r', ''), port: p.split(':')[1].replace('\r', '')});
        }
        cb(temp);
    });
}

fs.readFile('accounts.txt', (err, data) => {
    getProxList(function(proxList) {


        var timeout = 0;
        for (line of data.toString().split('\n')) {
            var prox = proxList[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxList.length) + 1];
            var username = line.split(':')[0].replace('\r', '');
            var password = line.split(':')[1].replace('\r', '');

            //if (prox.host === undefined || prox.port === undefined) { continue; }

            var usersList = getUsers();
            (function(h, p, us, pp, l, t) {
                setTimeout(function() { // TEST IT
                    console.log('Run: '+us);
                    console.log('L: '+l);
                    child_process.fork('./app.js', [h, p, us, pp, l]);
                }, t * 1000); // 5 sec
            })(prox.host, prox.port, username, password, usersList, timeout);
            timeout+=5; //60
        }
    });
});



// child_process.fork('./app.js', [username, password, friend.replace('\r', '')]);

}

exec_code();
setInterval(exec_code, 14400000)
```

Gets me error below:

```
mzapc@mzabox ~/X/test/works_Adder_without_delay
$ node start.js
C:\cygwin64\home\mzapc\X\test\works_Adder_without_delay\start.js:55
                        })(prox.host, prox.port, username, password, usersList, timeout);
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined
    at C:\cygwin64\home\mzapc\X\test\works_Adder_without_delay\start.js:55:11
    at C:\cygwin64\home\mzapc\X\test\works_Adder_without_delay\start.js:32:9
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

Thank you, 
best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable port is null or undefined. 
Check this line

```
var prox = proxList[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxList.length) + 1];
```

to see if you get some object from that.

**Edit.**

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * proxList.length) + 1
```

will get out of array range. For array of length 5 for example it can return value 5. And after you try

```
var prox = proxList[5] <- undefined
```

So to fix just do

```
 var prox = proxList[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxList.length)];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried to add if (prox.host === undefined || prox.port === undefined) { continue; } .. but still facing same error.. with prox.host.

Comment: You getting prox value from array by index. So im thinking in some cases your code goes out of array range and it's returning null.

Comment: so what to do in this case?, can you kindly edit code above?

Comment: Add fix in answer. Hope this helps.